# ALU result is 0, how to fix this?

Tags: memory, cpu, system-verilog, alu, rtl

In system-verilog I am trying to build a small ALU unit which takes a and calculates the negative value of it (-1) in a CPU.

I wrote:

```
 // Secondary ALU
 logic [31:0] negation_result;
 always_comb
    negation_result = 1'b0 - alu_a;
```

But the result saved in memory in hex is `00000000`

I changed `negation_result = 1'b0 - alu_a;` to `negation_result = 32'b1;` and now in memory I can see `00000001`

Any idea of what is causing this problem?

For example I have this ALU which works perfect:

```
logic [31:0] alu_result;
 always_comb
     case (alusel)
         ALU_ADD: alu_result = alu_a + alu_b;
         ALU_SUB: alu_result = alu_a - alu_b;
         ALU_SLL: alu_result = alu_a << alu_b;
         ALU_SLT: alu_result = (alu_as < alu_bs) ? 1 : 0;
         ALU_SLTU:alu_result = (alu_a < alu_b) ? 1 : 0;
         ALU_XOR: alu_result = alu_a ^ alu_b;
         ALU_SRL: alu_result = alu_a >> alu_b;
         ALU_SRA: alu_result = alu_a >>> alu_b;
         ALU_OR : alu_result = alu_a | alu_b;
         ALU_AND: alu_result = alu_a & alu_b;
         default: alu_result = alu_a + alu_b;
     endcase
```

Comment: Try changing `1'b0` to `32'b0` to match the size of your result.

Comment: @TomCarpenter didn't work still zeros in output

Comment: I think part of the problem is why it saves 00000001 in memory when I change it to negation_result=32'b1

Comment: It's cz 32'b1 is simply 1, not 1111...111 as u think. That is '1 in SV, not 32'b1.

Comment: What should you see? You never say what alu_a is. If it's 0, the logic is working correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How about give us the minimum code that shows the problem.

Comment: @MituRaj so how to correct it?

Comment: You need to add more details on what alu_a is and what is the value you expect.

Answer (score 1):

- Declare `negation_result` as `signed`.
- Then use
  `negation_result = -alu_a;` to negate the number.

Comment: But inverting the bits is **not** the same as negation.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers are represented in 2's complement form when you are operating on binary values. Simplest way to negate a number is: (by the definition of 2's complement):

1. take the bitwise complement of the number, i.e.: `alu_result = ~alu_a`
2. Add one to the result: `alu_result = alu_result + 1`

Check if you need to add `signed` in front of the logic definition.

Comment: The tilde `~` operator is the **bitwise-complement**, not negation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson do you aware of the 2's complement concept? Negative numbers are represented with 2's complement notation, and this requires taking the bitwise-complement and adding 1 to the result.

Comment: I am thoroughly aware of how 2's-complement works, and negating a number does not **require** taking the bitwise complement and adding 1...that is just one method. My comment concerns your step 1. where you say "take the bitwise **negation**" when in fact you are taking the bitwise **complement**. It is your wording that is incorrect, not the method.